# Finding root between two points

Tags: calculus, continuity, roots

The function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f(0)<0$, $f(1)>0$ and there is one root in between. Using $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, the expression $\frac{1\cdot f(0)-0\cdot f(1)}{f(0)-f(1)}$ would approximate the root.

Question is, if $f'(0)$ and $f'(1)$ are available too, what would an expression look like? I have been trying to solve and simplify some cubic equations with no success, and I think the problem might be simpler.

Comment: So to be sure that I unrestand. You want to find an approximation of a root, let's call it $x_0$. And you have only available $f(0), f(1), f'(0), f'(1)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a cubic equation you then have to find the solution of that equation... which is not very simple.

Instead I would suggest to take the two tangent lines in the points $(0,f(0))$ and $(1,f(1))$, find the two intersection of these lines and take the mean value of them, if both points are inside the interval. Otherwise if only one point is inside the interval take that point. If both points are outside, fall back to your original method.

But see also [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: I don't understand that, how can two lines have 2 intersections and how would you be sure they intersect at all?

Comment: That doesn't always work.  For example, both intersections could be negative.

Comment: Newton method happens to get out of [0,1]. I want some expression to always stay in the interval

Comment: I made some modifications to my answer.